# How to concat 2 foreign key columns?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've 2 tables Movies and Actor. Movie table has 2 columns, actor 1 and actor 2 which are foreign keys to Actor table which has all the actors.

In the `SELECT` Query I want to show both actor 1 and actor 2 as one column 
example (Actor1 , Actor2)

Movie table

```
Id     MovieName   Producer   Actor1    Actor2
1         X-man      prod1     1           2
2         Ant        Prod2     3           1
```

Actor table

```
Id  ActorName
1     Sam
2     Jhon
3     Brick
```

Result I want

```
Id     MovieName   Producer      Actors
1         X-man      prod1     Sam , Jhon
2         Ant        Prod2     Brick,Sam
```

Comment: You should consider fixing your movie table. You have violated 1NF with Actor1, Actor2. This is known as repeating groups. How are going to handle a third actor, or a fifty third? That should be a separate table of MovieActors.

Comment: @SeanLange any solution how can i fix this ?

Comment: Sure the fix is simple. That should be a separate table of MovieActors. You have a many to many relationship between movies and actors.

Comment: You might want to consider changing the design of your tables. Naturally, one actor can act in many movies and one movie can have many actors - typical many-to-many relationship. Have a look at the example of many-to-many relationship between students and classes [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab). In short, you need to add one more table which will serve as a "mapping" between movies and actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as asked you would need to join on to your Actor table twice, something like this `select Movie.id, MovieName, Producer, a1.Name+', '+a2.name as 'Actors' from Movie
INNER JOIN Actor a1 on Actor1 = a1.id
INNER JOIN Actor a2 on Actor2 = a2.id`

However, as pointed out in the comments you would ideally normalize your data more so your table structure was something like

```
CREATE TABLE Movie(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    MovieName nvarchar(50),
    Producer nvarchar(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE Actor(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE MovieActor(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY
    ActorId int,
    MovieId int);
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN Actor a1 on Actor1 = a1.id
INNER JOIN Actor a2 on Actor2 = a2.id`  

Actor1 and Actor2 column should be in movie table ?

Comment: Yes, we are saying we want to join the actor table to the movie table twice using the actor1 and actor2 columns. To make it clearer we can put the table names in as well, although it is not strictly necessary `INNER JOIN Actor a1 on Movie.Actor1 = a1.id INNER JOIN Movie.Actor a2 on Actor2 = a2.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Declare @movie table (id int, moviename varchar(50),producer varchar(50),actor1 int, actor2 int)

Declare @Actor table (Id int, Actorname varchar(50))

Insert into @movie values (1,'X-Man','Prod1',1,2)
Insert into @movie values (2,'ANt Man','Prod2',3,1)

insert into @Actor values (1,'Sam')
insert into @Actor values (2,'Jhon')
insert into @Actor values (3,'Brick')


select * from @Actor

select a.id,a.moviename,a.producer,b.Actorname + ',' + c.Actorname as actors from @movie a

join  @Actor b

on a.actor1=b.Id  

join @Actor c on c.Id=a.actor2
```